# Add an upload button on slack modal window

Tags: slack-api

I have a slack modal window
https://api.slack.com/surfaces/modals

I want to give the user an option to upload a file and send the content with the submit payload.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You can only place [block elements](https://api.slack.com/reference/block-kit/block-elements) on your modal and it (currently) does not include a file picker.